# items.py and nested xml tags with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to define items in items.py using scrapy and some tags have variable amounts of nested elements. I'm not sure how to represent this in items.py example:

item2.xml

```
<sponsors>
    <sponsor>
        foo
    </sponsor>
</sponsors>
```

item2.xml

```
<sponsors>
    <sponsor>
        foo
    </sponsor>
    <sponsor>
        bar
    </sponsor>
</sponsors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy's item fields don't force you to use any specific format. You can define it:

```
class YourItem(Item):
    sponsors = Field()
```

And just use a list:

```
item['sponsors'] = xpath.select('//sponsors/sponsor/text()').extract()
```